# Custom Menu Item Control Style in MahApps.Metro

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mahapps.metro

I created an MRU control for my project a while back and am now updating my UI using MahApps.Metro.  I need for the MRU Menu Item to have the same style as other menu items. My class inherits MenuItem and does not apply any style changes to itself:

```
Public Class MRUFileList
    Inherits MenuItem
    ...
End Class
```

I add it to my form like so:

```
<Menu>
    <mru:MRUFileList Name="mnuRecent" Header="Open _Recent" />
</Menu>
```

How do I apply the style of the MahApps.Metro menu item to my mru:MRUFileList menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `MetroMenuItem` style to your custom menu item should help.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MRUFileList}" BasedOn={StaticResource MetroMenuItem}>
```

or

```
<Menu>
    <mru:MRUFileList Name="mnuRecent" Header="Open _Recent" Style={DynamicResource MetroMenuItem} />
</Menu>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this.  Thanks!